# Problema com balanceamento de parenteses, em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Galera to com o seguinte código:

```
exp = str(input('Digite a expressão: '))
pilha = []
for simb in exp:
    if simb == '(':
        pilha.append('(')
    elif simb == ')':
        if len(pilha) > 0:
            pilha.pop()
    else:
        if simb == ')':
            pilha.append(')')
            break

if len(pilha) == 0:
    print('Sua expressão está "Correta"!')
else:
    print('Sua expressão está "Errada"!')
```

Se você executar o código colocando como exemplo:

```
(((2*2)-1)*(1+4)) assim parece correto
(((2*2)-1)*(1+4))) com parentese a mais do lado direito também aparece correto
((((2*2)-1)*(1+4)) agora com um parentese a mais do lado esquerdo aparece errado
ou seja ficou 
((())()) aparece certo
((())())) aparece certo
(((())()) aparece errado
```

Onde estou errando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trata-se de um problema conhecido como **balanceamento de parênteses**, e as soluções mais comuns sugerem pilha, fila e eliminação. <sup>[1](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-for-balanced-parentheses-in-python/)</sup> <sup>[2](https://pythonhelp.wordpress.com/2012/09/25/filas-e-pilhas-em-python/)</sup> <sup>[3](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/180567/checking-for-balanced-brackets-in-python)</sup>

Primeiro vamos ao problema em seu código:

```
    elif simb == ')':
        if len(pilha) > 0:
            pilha.pop()
    else:
        if simb == ')':
            pilha.append(')')
            break
```

A parte `else: if simb == ')':` é semelhante `elif simb == ')':`, portanto nunca será executada, já que a condição é satisfeita no elif.

O problema está em quando você encontra `len(pilha) == 0` (ou o `else` da condição `if len(pilha) > 0`, você ignora, mas este é antes de mais nada um parênteses desbalanceado, ou seja um fechamento antes da abertura.

Para corrigir isso você pode apenas alterar o `else` como parte do `if len(pilha)`, ficando:

```
for simb in exp:
    if simb == '(':
        pilha.append('(')
    elif simb == ')':
        if len(pilha) > 0:
            pilha.pop()
        else:
           pilha.append(')')
           break
```

Abaixo outra maneira de se resolver um pouco mais didática, com contador:

```
abertos = 0
for c in exp:
    if c == '(':
        abertos += 1
    elif c == ')':
        abertos -= 1
        if abertos < 0:
            break

print('balanceado' if abertos == 0 else 'desbalanceado')
```

Answer (score 0):

Em uma tradução livre [desse artigo na wikpedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brace_matching) (em portugues está estranho) "Parentheses matching, Brace matching ou bracket matching refere-se ao recurso chamado "realce de sintaxe" que certos editores de textos e ambientes de desenvolvimento oferecem realçando as aberturas e fechamentos de braces (parenteses, colchetes, ou chaves)". Como diz o artigo, o conceito engloba a abertura e fechamento não só dos parenteses, mas também dos outros "braces", apresento abaixo um algoritmo para esse problema e, em seguida, a codificação em python.

> Algoritmo:
>
> 1. Percorra toda a expressão checando cada caracter;
> 2. Se o caracter não for um bracket, ignore;
> 3. Se for um bracket de abertura, adicione-o à pilha;
> 4. Se for um bracket de fechamento:
>      4.1 Retorne `False` se o ultimo caracter da pilha não for um bracket de abertura correspondente;
> 5. Remova o bracket de abertura correspondente da pilha;
> 6. No final retorne `True` se a pilha estiver vazia, se não retorne `False`.

Código em python:

```
def parenthesis_matching(brackets):
    __open = ['(', '{', '[']
    __close = [')', '}', ']']
    __stack = []
    if brackets=='':
        return False
    for b in brackets:
        if b in __open:
            __stack.append(b)
        elif b in __close:
            if __stack==[]:
                return False
            open_b = __open[ __close.index(b) ]
            last = __stack.pop()
            if not open_b == last:
                return False
    return True if __stack==[] else False     

# Expressoes para testar o código    
exps = []
exps.append('(a[0]+b[2c[6]]) {24+53}')
exps.append('f(e(d))')
exps.append('[()]{}([])')
exps.append('((b)')
exps.append('(c]')
exps.append('{(a[])')
exps.append('([)]')
exps.append(')(')
exps.append('{[(stackoverflow),(parenthesis_matching(brackets))]}')

# Testando o codigo
for e in exps:
    print(e+' : ', parenthesis_matching(e))
```

Saida:

```
(a[0]+b[2c[6]]) {24+53} :  True
f(e(d)) :  True
[()]{}([]) :  True
((b) :  False
(c] :  False
{(a[]) :  False
([)] :  False
)( :  False
{[(stackoverflow),(parenthesis_matching(brackets))]} :  True
```

[Veja funcionando no repl.it](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/parenthesismatching).